# Function is not iterating through classes

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I am creating a webpage with multiple divs that are supposed to perform the same task. I am attempting to add the same button functionality to each div which toggles between showing and hiding the provided text. I realized that I have to use document.getElementsByClassName and iterate through the classes in order to provide the javascript functionality to each button. For some reason, it is not working for me and when I inspect the console in devtools, I get an error message stating, **"food.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: foodInfo.addEventListener is not a function
at food.js:3"** What could I be doing wrong here?

html

```
<div class='top'>
            <div class='blue'>
             <p class='top-left'>Seaside on the Pier</p>
             <p class='top-left'>Sandwich Shop · Grill · Rooftop Lounge Now Open!</p>
             <p class='top-left details'>Hours: M-T 11AM – 10P, F-Sa 11AM – 11PM, Su 11AM – 9PM
              Phone: (310) 883-7437</p>
             <button type='button' onclick ='foodInfo()'>Details</button>
            </div>

            <div class='dark-green'>
              <p class='top-right'>The Albright</p>
              <p class='top-right'>You’re at the ocean, it’s only natural to partake. 
                A wide array of seafood options combined with open-air patio dining for a 
                pleasant Pier experience.</p>
              <p class='top-right details'>Hours: M-F, 12PM-9PM, Sa & Su 11AM-10PM
                Phone: (310) 394-9683</p>
              <button type='button' onclick ='foodInfo()'>Details</button>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

js

```
let foodInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('details')

foodInfo.addEventListener('click', () => {
    for(i=0; i < foodInfo.length; i++) {
        if(foodInfo.style.display === 'none') {
            foodInfo.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            foodInfo.style.display = 'none';
        }
```

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) does not return a single HTML element (which would have an `addEventListener` function); It returns an *array* of HTML elements....

Comment: Right.. Which is why I am attempting to iterate through the array with the for loop listed in the js code.

Comment: You call `let foodInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('details');` and then you attempt to use `foodInfo.addEventListener` *outside* your loop ... that function doesn't exist on foodInfo because foodInfo is not an [`EventTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget), it is an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Comment: I see what you mean. Now if that is the case, how would I list the 'onclick' function on the html page?  I corrected the code based off of what you just mentioned and now I am receiving  'foodInfo is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.onclick'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access each item in the array inside your for loop. You can do this by using the index of the for loop.

Then you can add the event listener to each object in the array.

```
for (i = 0; i < foodInfo.length; i++) {
    foodInfo[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(this.style.display === 'none') {
            this.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            this.style.display = 'none';
        }
    })
}
```

You also have this in your HTML on your button. This causes an error as there is not a function called foodInfo, foodInfo is your array.

```
onclick="foodInfo()"
```

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about the if/else logic in this answer too. The original logic iterated over all elements *when any element is clicked*, your simplification to use `this` only affects the clicked element. Secondly, you can't click on an element that isn't displayed, so the first if case is never entered for *this* logic. (In the original question it *is* entered.)

Comment: Yes, you make a good point and the code may have other issues, I was just addressing the main question first.

Comment: I'm saying your answer doesn't reproduce the same *side effects* that the logic in the question does, which may be an intentional design.

Comment: Romen is right. We need to know what is meant to be clicked and what is meant to be shown/hidden to provide a better answer.

Comment: Your answer's change to the logic does seem more *useful* though. The original logic will just hide everything, including the element you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t make sense to listen for clicks on a collection... it's not possible!

Also, to operate on the ELEMENTS of a collection, instead of...

```
for(i=0; i < foodInfo.length; i++) {

    if(foodInfo.style.display === 'none') {
        foodInfo.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        foodInfo.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

You have to go...

```
 for(i=0; i < foodInfo.length; i++) {

    if(foodInfo[i].style.display === 'none') {
        foodInfo[i].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        foodInfo[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer has *different side-effects* than the logic you included in your question. This answer is just to provide a true "fix" for your code that has the same the side effects that would occur with the logic you provided.

```
// Get all of the elements that have the `details` class
var foodInfo = document.getElementsByClassName('details')

// Iterate over each element
for (let i=0; i<foodInfo.length; i++) {
    // Assign a click event listener to each 'details' element
    foodInfo[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        // On click, **for each 'details' element in the page**
        for (let j=0; j < foodInfo.length; j++) {
            // Toggle the display between 'block' and 'none'
            if (foodInfo[j].style.display === 'none')
                foodInfo[j].style.display = 'block';
            else
                foodInfo[j].style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
}
```

*Possible side-effects may include hiding all of your `details` elements when any of them are clicked. Consult your stakeholders before use.*